# Identify subscribers during subscription

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

Assume that I have some subscriber implementation:

```
// SafeSubscriber extension doesn't matter here - the problem exists for simple Subscriber implementations too
class ParticularSubscriber<T> extends SafeSubscriber<T> {

    private Subscriber<T> actual;

    public ParticularSubscriber() {
        super(Subscribers.create(System.out::println));
    }
}
```

Then, I need to create an observer that performs some extra configurations depending on the subscriber passed. Naive approach first:

```
Observable<String> o = Observable.<String>create(subscriber -> {
    if(subscriber instanceof ParticularSubscriber) {
        // do some extra logic here.
    }
});
```

It is successfully works if we directly subscribe to the Observable o:

```
o.subscribe(new ParticularSubscriber<>());
```

But things changed if we apply some operations on it:

```
o.map(str -> str + 1)
        .filter(str -> str != "")
        .subscribe(new ParticularSubscriber<>());
```

In the latter case, some wrapper is passed to OnSubscribe. Deeply inside this wrapper there is my initial ParticularSubscriber, but I have no ability to get to it.

Is there any way to access initially passed subscriber in the observer's callbacks?

Comment: That should not be possible otherwise one could call target subscriber's methods directly, skipping logic from downstream operators. Instead you can create different observables based on subscriber type: it could be method `getObservable(Subscriber targetSubs) { if(targetSubs instanceOf ParticularSubscriber) return observable1 else return observable2`

Comment: I thought the same way first - it is right that initial subscriber is encapsulated behind. Let me reformulate my question a bit: is there a way to pass some meta-information describing subscriber's part to the already created observable?